# How to force close a child popup window or clear the cache child popup window

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function to open PDFs in one new window when user clicks on pdf hyperlinks. The win variable is a global variable to make sure pdf opens in the same window instead of each pdf click open a new window (minimize the number of windows). However, when click on a new PDF hyperlink, I saw the PDF url is passed from code behind correctly, but the window still displays the old PDF. The old PDF is cached for sure. How can I remove the cache of the PDF window or force the old pdf window to close (win.close() is not working for me here) when a new PDF link is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var win;
function OpenPDFFile(PDF_URL)
{
if (win != null) {
win.close();
}
win= window.open(PDF_URL, "Popup", "resizable=1, width=750, height=600");
win.location.reload(); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please only include SO question tags relevant to your question.

Comment: You should open and close the tag by using the same tagname: `<script>...</script>`

Comment: thank you for point it out. it was a mistake in the question but not in the actual code, I have corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

$('#id_of_modal').modal('hide'); or $('#id_of_Model').modal('toggle');

Comment: Is “id_of_modal” the Id of the pop up window? Can you please explain it in details? Thank you!